# How do I create a new room in socket io for each id in a route

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have a route set up as `app.get('/page/:id')`

I want each one of those ids to have their own socket io room but I'm not sure how to do so.

This is what I have so far.

app.js:

```
var server = app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('Server started on port 3000');
});

var discussionServer = require('./lib/discussion-server.js');
discussionServer.listen(server, 'Default');
```

discussion-server.js:

```
var socketio = require('socket.io');

exports.listen = function(server, room) {
  io = socketio.listen(server);  
  var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
  io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.join(room);
    socket.on('message', function(message) {
      io.to(room).emit('message', message);
    });
  });
}
```

Right now the socket io connection works but it obviously the same room for every id in my app because I am never changing rooms.

I want to be able to pass in a value to the socket io connection depending on the `id` in the route so each route will have a unique socket io room. So instead of `'Default'` in `discussionServer.listen(server, 'Default')`, I would like to pass in the id of the route.

Comment: Do you mean a room for 'page' or a room for every new 'id'?

Comment: @Tholle every new id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could emit the `room` you like to join from the frontend like:

```
var room = getRoom();
io.connect().emit('join room', {room: room});
```

and then on the backend side:

```
socket.on('join room', function (data) {
    socket.join(data.room);
    ...
}
```

Hope this helps!